# connecting fluttter to sql with physical phone isnt working

Tags: sql, flutter, dart, mysql-workbench

**here is the snippet of code that connects me to the SQL server when using it in normal dart it works just fine but when trying to connect it to flutter and use it in my physical phone it doesn't work.**
I'm using MySQL workbench as the SQL server in my pc, i created a connection and specified the ***localhost*** as  my host in the SQL server with the ***3306*** port,
and in my flutter dart app i specified the host as my pc ip address but it give me the error ***"ip address" is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server.***

```
Future<void> connect() async{
    conn = await MySqlConnection.connect(
      ConnectionSettings(
          host:computer/server ip address,
      user: my_user,
      port:3306,
      password: password,
      db: my db)
    );
  }
```

Comment: whats the ip you are using?

Answer (score -1):

The error you are encountering ("IP address" is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server) typically indicates that the MySQL server is configured to reject connections from certain IP addresses for security reasons. Here are a few steps you can take to troubleshoot and resolve the issue:

Check MySQL User Permissions:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON your_database.* TO 'your_user'@'your_ip_address' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Verify IP Address Format:

```
Future<void> connect() async {
  conn = await MySqlConnection.connect(
    ConnectionSettings(
      host: 'your_server_ip_address',
      port: 3306,
      user: 'your_user',
      password: 'your_password',
      db: 'your_db',
    ),
  );
}
```